# How to add user to VSTS Group visualstudio.com

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, azure-devops, tfvc

I need to add a colleague to my development environment (specifically VisualStudioOnline - TFS) and the doc I've read about how to do this shows differently than what I see when I try.

I am the only user of Visual Studio 2012 in my small company. I am using Visual Studio Online for Source Control (as I understand it, this exposes Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Service - Version 15.115.26417.0 as a "service" (i.e. this is the cloud...there is no on-premise TFS installed). Currently, I am using a LOCAL workspace (the default) and TFVC (not GIT).

I added my NewUserA to the Administrators group on the dev server. When click menu item Team to Connect to TFS, I am prompted to sign-in with my "Microsoft" account.

However, when I try to add NewUserA to my TFS, the dialog below seems unable to search for the existence of NewUserA:
[image]

It seems to want an "identity" of NewUserA (which suggests an email address too) so it sort of makes sense that this prompt does not look for locally added Windows users.

I am quite confused and would appreciate being helped thru this.

Comment: Your understanding of VSTS is slightly incorrect. It's not a specific on-premises version of TFS hosted in the cloud -- it's a separate platform from the same code base as on-premises TFS. However, it receives updates much more frequently than on-premises TFS, and as such features available in VSTS may not be available in TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your VSTS account isn't connected to Azure Active Directory and you're not synchronizing your on-premises AD to AAD, then of course it won't be able to find users from your on-prem domain. If that's the case, you can add users by email address and they'll be prompted to sign up for a Microsoft account (if they don't already have one) using that address. This is different than an organizational account, which is what you'd use if you were connected to Azure AD.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I added someone by typing only their email address and their "display name" showed properly. That person already had a Microsoft account. For a user with no MSFT account, what is the syntax for adding someone's display name and then their email account (i.e. FirstName LastName;someone.email@somedomain.com ?)

Comment: @JohnAdams Register a new Microsoft account, then add it to your VSTS.